# A way to group a list of names from a CSV file based on part of name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Im currently trying to get an overview of our computers at work.

All the computer names are based on geographic location and department and i have a CSV file with all the computers listed.

At almost 11.000 computers and a combination of 41 geographical locations and 72 departmens i dont know where to begin.

Right now all the computers are listed in alphabetical order, like:

- XUSAIT001
- XUSAIT002
- XCANHR001

And so on, and i would like to group all computers with XUSAIT??? into one group with a counter, preferably minimized so a department with 400 computers dont show all of them in a list.

What im looking for is looking something like this:

- XUSANYC??? - 10
- XCANHR??? - 20

Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do all the codes you want to keep have the same length? If yes, then you can use `LEFT()` function to get them in a helper column, then use a pivot table (or `COUNTIF`) for counting.

Comment: Unfortunately not, most of them have a name like XUSAIT001 but some departments have over 1000 at the end.

Comment: Is the count of letters always the same at the beginning of the code? Is it always followed by a number? Can you please post expected output for the sample data you've already posted? Please don't answer in comment, but update your question.

Comment: I hope i got this right, i've updated the original post with some more information, @MátéJuhász

Comment: The numbers at the end do not matter.  So long as the letter positions are fixed, you can easily use string functions to split them up, then group with Pivot Table or SubTotal or Countifs as suggested @MátéJuhász

Comment: Huge thanks @MátéJuhász and Ron Rosenfeld, i updated the original post with the solution i got with your help.

Comment: Great you could solve it. Please post it as answer instead of updating your question, that way it'll be more cleat for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution with the help of Máté Juhász and Ron Rosenfeld and boy it was embarrassingly simple. I paste all the computer names in column A, in column B i use the `LEFT()` function to only show the first 7 letters of the name so i get prefix + location + department "XUSAECO".

Copy both columns over to a Pivot Table and show Rows and Value and i get a counter for each entry of a specific combination of location and department.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

*Finally I got the Solution. For each Country you need to apply a minor modification in the Formula.

I tried to make it Dynamic but Country Code has some issue. I'm trying to find the remedy of it also.*

**Meanwhile, you can proceed with this one.**

[image]

**Formula for USA:**

```
=COUNTIF($A$560:$A$574,"XUSA"&D560&"*?*")
```

**Formula for CANADA:**

```
=COUNTIF($A$560:$A$574,"XCAN"&D563&"*?*")
```

Likewise use XFRA for France & others.

**NB:** Drag the Formula Down, Cell D560 has Department Code like IT, HR, COPC downwards and Value in RED are Country Total.

**Hope this help and possibly you or others find clue for the better one.**

Comment: OP has 41 locations * 72 departments,  writing a formula manually for each of them sounds long:(

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, Yeah that's the reason I've mentioned on top that still I'm in search of something better but for the time this could help him,,! Did you find something magical ?